# Spring Boot CQRS Example cannot work with mvn clean install

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I try to implement an example of CQRS in Spring Boot. I have two main modules named as bank-account and cqrs-core. bank-account comprises 3 modules which are account-cmd, account-common and account-query.

When I try to run this command `cqrs-example\bank-account> mvn clean install` under bank-account directory, I get this issue shown below.

```
[INFO] cqrs.core .......................................... SUCCESS [  7.474 s]
[INFO] account.common ..................................... FAILURE [  2.248 s] 
[INFO] account.cmd ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] account.query ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] bank-account ....................................... SKIPPED


[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
10.1:compile (default-compile) on project account.common: Compilation failure: C
ompilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsDepositedEvent.java:[
3,44] package com.bankcqrsexample.cqrs.core.events does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsDepositedEvent.java:[
13,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class BaseEvent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsDepositedEvent.java:[
12,1] package BaseEvent does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsWithdrawnEvent.java:[
3,44] package com.bankcqrsexample.cqrs.core.events does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsWithdrawnEvent.java:[
13,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class BaseEvent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/FundsWithdrawnEvent.java:[
12,1] package BaseEvent does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountOpenedEvent.java:[4
,44] package com.bankcqrsexample.cqrs.core.events does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountOpenedEvent.java:[1
6,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class BaseEvent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountOpenedEvent.java:[1
5,1] package BaseEvent does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountClosedEvent.java:[3
,44] package com.bankcqrsexample.cqrs.core.events does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountClosedEvent.java:[1
1,41] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class BaseEvent
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Username/IdeaProjects/cqrs-example/bank-account/account.common/sr
c/main/java/com/bankcqrsexample/account/common/events/AccountClosedEvent.java:[9
,1] package BaseEvent does not exist
```

What is the problem in account-common?

When I try to run this command `\cqrs-example\cqrs.core\cqrs.core> mvn clean install`, it is successfully built.

How can I fix it?

Here is my repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/cqrs-example)

Comment: Could you please provide a way to reproduce the problem? Did you already try to solve the problem, and are there some problems that you encountered?

Comment: @MJG I could get this issue com.bankcqrsexample.cqrs.core.events does not exist when I run mvn clean install under bank-account. The package is already defined. Pom.xml is also defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revised both Dockerfile files as shown below and the issue disappeared. I have no idea why it didn't work.

account.cmd

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} account.cmd.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/account.cmd.jar"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

account.query

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} account.query.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/account.query.jar"]

EXPOSE 5001
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it all looks fine from the Maven point of view.

What is missing, according to Java-17: `module-info.java` to core and common (and all the others as well).

Try to use Java-8 instead.

Otherwise the Compiler will not open scope for the classpath-portion of the dependencies, as it does require clear definitions of

- export
- requires
- opens if needed

to make java-packages available to dependent libraries.